# Google Maps API v3 sometimes doesn't load full size. Why?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

on my page [www.mappeze.de](http://www.mappeze.de/Lage_und_Anfahrt) sometimes (not everytime) the Map doesn't appear in full size.

Look this [picture](http://www3.mappeze.de/google-maps-api-3_Problem.png).

Can anyone tell me why?

Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading the map by calling initialize() right after the creation of the div that should contain the map.  That may be to early in some cases(may depend on the users environment), because it may happen that the desired size of the div cannot be detected, because it's not rendered yet.

Call initialize when the page is loaded, e.g.

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

Comment: Thanx for the idea! :) 
seTimeout("initialize()", 500); could be helpful, too?

Comment: Depends how slow the computer of the user is and how long it may take to load?